# Time series Variability

Tags: time-series, variability

How to understand variabilty between output and input variable, can someone help me in understanding how mean, variance and sd will help in identifying relation between them.[image]

I have added a glimpse of my data 
TAI is input variable and TP is output variable between which i would like to know variability

Comment: The covariance is used to measure the variability ( inter-dependence/ correlation) between an output and an input variable

Comment: I have a input variable as estimated time and other variables and output variable as real production time, i wanted to see the variability between estimated time and poduction time. to see if there is any relationship between them . When i check other articles it shows it can be done using Variance mean and sd but i dont know how to understand this concept?

Comment: post your data and I might be able to help further